# Spring: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Tags: java, spring

I could not find a solution on this site to the following problem when I use **Spring with annotations** (not XML).

**Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?**

I have the following simple class. I do not extend it somewhere else.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Matryoshka
{
    private Matryoshka[] matryoshki;

    public Matryoshka(Matryoshka[] matryoshki)
    {
        this.matryoshki = matryoshki;
    }
}
```

Then I try to create instances of this class by Spring's `<T> T BeanFactory.getBean(Class<T> var1, Object... var2)`

From within a Spring scanned class I do something like:

```
Matryoshka matryoshka = new Matryoshka(new Matryoshka[] {});
matryoshka = applicationContext.getBean(matryoshka.getClass(), new Matryoshka[] {matryoshka, matryoshka});
//matryoshka = (Matryoshka) applicationContext.getBean("matryoshka", new Matryoshka[] {matryoshka, matryoshka}); //also gives same error
```

Error message is:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'matryoshka' defined in file [/home/...../Matryoshka.class]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)`

**UPDATE:**

It looks like `BeanFactory.getBean(Class<T> var1, Object... var2)` works when the constructor of the bean I try to instantiate has a fixed number of parameters. E.g.

`public Matryoshka(Matryoshka matryoshki1, Matryoshka matryoshki2)`,

but not `public Matryoshka(Matryoshka[] matryoshki)`

or `public Matryoshka(Matryoshka... matryoshki)`.

Is it possible to make Spring work with constructors with indefinite number of parameters?

I have seen something similar (not a constructor though) in the following answer

[A function I want to Spring-inject takes varargs. Should I provide an overload that takes a list instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542043/a-function-i-want-to-spring-inject-takes-varargs-should-i-provide-an-overload-t)

but they used XML configuration.

Comment: Afaik with componentscan Spring tries to instantiate this before you even call the getBean method and therefore could not resolve the matching constructor as it is a circular reference to the class itself. You might need an Autowired annotation on the constructor or create a default constructor too.

Comment: Hmmmm I don't get any exception when I don't try to instantiate through `getBean`. I think adding `Autowired` on a constructor would cause Spring to automatically try to create an instance, however it would require instances of the parameters in the cnotext - but I don't know how it should behave in case of vararg parameters and/or circular initialization, but anyway this is not what I want to do here.

Comment: Looks like problem is not related to circular reference. I tried to replace the constructor parameter with array of String. Still same error.