# Error when constructing a spring bean of an object with one Enum, and then a vararg of enums

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have the following object and constructor:

```
public class Options {
    public Options(Enum option, Enum... moreOptions) {
        // My code...
    }

    public Enum build(String nameOfEnum) {
        // Creates enum....
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a spring bean for it using the following xml, based off an answer to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751400/how-to-xml-configure-spring-bean-for-constructor-injection-when-bean-has-varargs):

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.mypackage.Options">
    <constructor-arg value="#{Options.build('firstEnum')}" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>#{Options.build('secondEnum')}"</value>
            <value>#{Options.build('thirdEnum')}"</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
<bean>
```

I just run into the following error, however:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name myBean defined in ServletContext resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.lang.Enum[]]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [[Ljava.lang.Enum;]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Enum[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Enum]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I've tried some variations on my current spring config, like having all values in the list, or just creating each value on its own. None seem to work.

How do I correctly create my spring bean?